# AppleScript "do shell script" ignores PATH Variable

Tags: android, macos, applescript, xamarin

I'm trying to build an automated build script with applescript on MacOS X.

For now everything works correctly with one glitch.

The command **"do script ("zipalign -f -v 4 /tmp/src.apk /tmp/tgt.apk")** works fine if I run it in a separate tell for application "Terminal" but leaves the terminal window open when it's done. Everything else in the script works fine in tells for application "Finder".

If I try to run the command via **"do shell script"** inside the tell for "Finder" I only get an error **"command not found"**.

The path to **zipalign** is set in **/etc/paths** and is reachable through any terminal window and **"do shell"** but not to **"do shell script"** command.

What is the correct way to ensure that **"do shell script"** uses $PATH to find commands or alternatively is there a bulletproof way to close the terminal left by **"do script"**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you invoke bash as an interactive login shell, the paths in `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d/*` are added to `PATH` by `/usr/libexec/path_helper`, which is run from `/etc/profile`. `do shell script` invokes bash as sh and as a non-interactive non-login shell, which does not read `/etc/profile`.

You can run path_helper manually though:

```
do shell script "eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`; echo $PATH"
```

Comment: Tried it and doesn't seem to change anything. Your command prints the current $PATH including all entries from /etc/paths, but neither concatenating my command nor starting it from within in a new 'do shell script' works. The Errormessage remains the same... - what makes me wonder is that a manually started /bin/sh from within bash has no problem in finding $PATH or the command -.- Any further suggestions?

Comment: How did you concatenate it? I have `/usr/local/bin` in `/etc/paths`, so `do shell script "eval $(/usr/libexec/path_helper -s); wget -h"` runs `/usr/local/bin/wget`. If you run `sh` in a normal terminal window, it inherits environment variables from the current shell.

Comment: This did it^^ I didn't used parenthesis around the eval parameter, thanks alot :)

Comment: ``do shell script "eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`; /bin/bash --init-file ~/.profile; /usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/gvim &> /dev/null &"``

Answer (score 0):

Though this question was four years ago, but I think the simplest answer is needed to be told. I use the command 'wkhtmltopdf' (which is used to print pdf and it is placed in `/usr/local/bin`) for example

```
--past
wkhtmltopdf out.html out.pdf
--now
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin; wkhtmltopdf out.html out.pdf
```

It just add new PATH variable to the sh process called up by AppleScript.